Second (and higher) derivatives of the adjugate operator for singular matrix
Consider the operator
$$
f(A): A \rightarrow adj(A)
$$
The derivative $Df_A (H)$ was given here and depends on the rank. I am interested in the second (and higher) derivatives in the $rank(A) = n-1$ case.
Simply differentiating the resulting formula given in the linked answer does not work because the pseudo inverse is not differentiable at the singularity.
Instead, I tried to derive the second derivative analogously as in the given answer by differentiating Jacobi's formula a second time and then taking the limit of $S_t$ for $t \rightarrow 0$. However, I am getting stuck because I do not really understand how the linked answer went from equations $3$, $4$ and $5$ to $6$ or if this approach really leads to the goal.
In the end, I am interested in a procedure that can be implemented numerically efficiently, so directly working with Laplace's formula does not work.

What is $n$ in $rank(A)=n-1$?

$n$ is the dimension of $A$, so $A \in R^{n \times n}$
